# Long table to fit on 2 pages

Tags: tables, page-breaking, longtable

In a middle of a page I have a long table with a lot of maths formulas and I would like to make it fit on 2 pages automatically.

Here the code :

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  %%% new
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amscd}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[page]{appendix}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{amsfonts,bbm}
\usepackage[retainorgcmds]{IEEEtrantools}

\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage{supertabular} % tableaux qui tiennent sur plusieurs pages

%\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\def\ds{\displaystyle}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{syntonly}
\usepackage{tracefnt}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\addtolength{\textwidth}{1.6cm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace} % permet de définir l'interligne
\usepackage{a4wide}
%%\usepackage{xtab} %% commented out because loading this package causes an error



%\textheight 22.5cm \textwidth 15.8cm
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{hmargin=3cm,vmargin=3cm}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LYX's packages
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{esint}
\PassOptionsToPackage{normalem}{ulem}
\usepackage{ulem}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\bea}{\begin{eqnarray*}}
\newcommand{\eea}{\end{eqnarray*}}
\newcommand{\cc}{\mathcal}
\newcommand{\bb}{\mathbb}
\newcommand{\bacc}{\left\{}
\newcommand{\eacc}{\right\}}
\newcommand{\evacc}{\right.}
\newcommand{\bp}{\left(}
\newcommand{\ep}{\right)}
\newcommand{\bint}{\left[}
\newcommand{\eint}{\right]}
%\newcommand{\bea}{\begin{eqnarray*}}
%\newcommand{\eea}{\end{eqnarray*}}
\newcommand{\bnorme}{\left\|}
\newcommand{\enorme}{\right\|}
\newcommand{\babsolu}{\left|}
\newcommand{\eabsolu}{\right|}
\newcommand{\ba}{\begin{array}}
\newcommand{\ea}{\end{array}}
\newcommand{\bdes}{\begin{description}}
\newcommand{\edes}{\end{description}}
\newcommand{\benu}{\begin{enumerate}}
\newcommand{\eenu}{\end{enumerate}}
\newcommand{\implique}{\Rightarrow}
\newcommand{\ssi}{\Leftrightarrow}
\newcommand{\associe}{\mapsto}
\newcommand{\avaleur}{\rightarrow}
\newcommand{\rn}{$\mathbb{R}^N$}
\newcommand{\sla}{\textbackslash}
%\newcommand{\pp}{\textit{Preuve.}}
\newcommand{\bdisp}{\begin{displaymath}}
\newcommand{\edisp}{\begin{displaymath}}
\newcommand{\bsplit}{\begin{split}}
\newcommand{\esplit}{\end{split}}
\newcommand{\petit}{\footnotesize}
\newtheorem{deff}{Définition}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[deff]{Lemme}
\newtheorem{prop}[deff]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{thm}[deff]{Théorème}
\newtheorem{coro}[deff]{Corollaire}
\newtheorem{rmq}[deff]{Remarque}
\newcommand{\pre}{{\textit{\petit{{\textbf{Démonstration.  }}}}}}
\newcommand{\p}{\mathbb{P}}
\newcommand{\pp}{\mathbb{P}^{'}}
\newcommand{\ppp}{\mathbb{P}^{''}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\BB}{\mathscr{B}}
\newcommand{\KK}{\mathscr{K}}
\newcommand{\CC}{\mathcal{C}}
\newcommand{\X}{\mathsf{X}}

\newcommand{\YY}{\mathsf{Y}}

\newcommand{\HH}{\mathsf{H}}
\newcommand{\XX}{\mathsf{X}}
\newcommand{\NN}{\mathsf{N}}
\newcommand{\RR}{\mathsf{R}}
\newcommand{\EE}{\mathsf{E}}
\newcommand{\FF}{\mathsf{F}}
\newcommand{\MM}{\mathsf{M}}
\newcommand*{\defeq}{\mathrel{\vcenter{\baselineskip0.5ex \lineskiplimit0pt
                     \hbox{\scriptsize.}\hbox{\scriptsize.}}}% definie le symbole :=
                     =}

\begin{document} %%% new

{\textbf{fonctions de référence}}

$$\begin{array}{ll}

\displaystyle{\tau(n)=\mbox{card\,}\bacc p\, /\, p\mbox{ divise }n\eacc}
& \displaystyle{\mu(n)=\bacc\ba{ccc}0&\mbox{ si }
&n\not\in \pp\\ (-1)^{\tau(n)}
&\mbox{ si }&n\in \pp\ea\right.} \mbox{\petit{(fonction de Möbius)}}\\\\
\displaystyle{{\delta(n)=\sum_{k/n}\mu(k)}}
&\Lambda (n)=\bacc\ba{ccc}0
&\mbox{ si }
&n\not\in \ppp\\
\log(p)
&\mbox{ si }
&n= \p^\nu\ea\right.\mbox{\petit{(fonction de Mangoldt)}}\\\\
\displaystyle{b(n)=\sum_{kl=n}\Lambda(k)\,\Lambda (l)-\Lambda(n)\log(n)}
&\displaystyle{c(n)=\sum_{kl=n}\Lambda(k)\,\Lambda (l)+\Lambda(n)\log(n)}\\\\
\displaystyle{[x]=\sum_{k\leq x}1} (\petit{\mbox{partie entière de }} $x$)
& \beta(x)=x-[x] (\petit{\mbox {partie fractionnaire de }} x)\\
\ &\ \\
\pi(x)=\mbox{card}\bacc p\in\p\,/\, p\leq x\eacc&\pi'(x)=\mbox{card}\bacc p'\in\pp\,/\, p'\leq x\eacc\\
\ &\ \\
U(x)=\displaystyle{\sum_{k\leq x}\frac{x}{k}}&M(x)=\displaystyle{\sum_{k\leq x} \mu(k)} \mbox{\petit{(fonction de Mertens)}}\\
\ &\ \\
V(x)=\displaystyle{\sum_{k\leq x}\frac{x}{k}\log\bp\frac{x}{k}\ep}& \varphi(x)=\babsolu M(x)\eabsolu \log^2 x-2x\log x\\
\ &\ \\
\sigma(x)=\displaystyle{\sup_{t\geq x}\babsolu \frac{M(t)}{t}\eabsolu}& \nu_p(x)=\bint \frac{\log (x)}{\log (p)}\eint=\bacc\ba{ccc}0&\mbox{ si }&p>x\\
\max\bacc \nu/\ p^\nu\leq x\eacc&\mbox{ si }&p\leq x\ea\right.\\
\ &\ \\
\theta(x)=\displaystyle{\sum_{p\leq x}\log(p)}&\Psi(x)=\displaystyle{\sum_{p\leq x}\nu_p(x)\log(p)}=\displaystyle{\sum_{n\leq x}\Lambda (n)}\mbox{\petit{ (f. de Tchebychev)}}
\end{array}$$

\end{document} %%% new
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! A quick note: By indenting lines of code by four spaces -- easily done by highlighting the lines and clicking on the `{}` "button" in the line above the edit window -- the code will be pretty-printed automatically.

Comment: A separate comment: Your code seems to have quite a few custom macros -- `\bacc`, `eacc`, `\pp`, `\ba`, and `\ea`, to name but the first few -- that aren't defined in the code fragment you've posted. Please edit your posting to create an MWE (minimum working example, i.e., a program that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`) that compiles and illustrates the issues you're looking to fix.

Comment: Yes will do it right now

Comment: you have edited the example but it is still not a complete document so people can still not use it

Comment: Actually the complete doc takes 43 pages !! this will be hard to follow for the reader I think.

Comment: You have tagged this `longtable` but haven't used that package (which would allow mult-page tables, or you could use an amsalignment. don't do `(x)=\displaystyle{ ...` as `\displaystyle` does not take a `{}` argument the setting applies to the entire math list including the `(x)=` that comes _before` `\displaystyle`

Comment: I am looking to make a part of this table goes down automatically on the next page

Comment: You still haven't defined the macros `\p`, `\pp`, `\ppp`, and `\petit`. You would have noticed the absence of their definitions had you created an MWE rather than extended code snippets.

Comment: Please see the help pages for this site on how to construct a _minimal_ example. Your original document is not relevant but you should remove _all_ packages not required to show the problem but make the example _complete_ so people can (a) see the problem and (b) test their answers

Comment: I am putting all the header right now. Sorry I am really a biginner on Latex

Comment: I tried using supertabular and Longtable but it did not work

Comment: So your document produces `! LaTeX Error: Command \tablehead already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
`   If that is not the problem you are asking about please fix the example not to make it.

Comment: yes I have this error David

Comment: But that error is unrelated to the question. Look remove every package that is unrelated to the question you load amsmath at  at least three times and you never want to load syntolnly or epsfig and you load xtab and supertab and graphics and enumerate and don't use them. You need to give people half a chance to help you.

Comment: Can I put all my .tex here ?

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding a few instructions (and uncommenting the command that loads the `xtab` package) to make your code snippets into a (not so) minimal working example. I've also added a screenshot of the result. Please (re)state what exactly you're looking to achieve.

Comment: @Mico thanks. In fact it was the xtab package the problem.

What I need now is to make this table fit on 2 pages automatically. Because this table start in the middle of a page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your setup correctly, you're not really looking to create a `table` (or `supertabular`, etc) in the usual LaTeX sense of the word. Instead, you're creating a longer listing of unnumbered equations, two per row. If this interpretation is correct, you could use an `align*` environment, with three alignment points marked with `&`. The directive `\allowdisplaybreaks`, placed before `\begin{align*}`, permits line breaks after each row.

I can't help but comment on the facts that (a) there are a lot of duplicative instructions in your preamble, with several packages being loaded three and even four times, and (b) a lot of the math-related shortcuts you've created don't cut down significantly on the amount of typing you need to do. Cleaning up this situation isn't just good for aesthetics but will also improve your understanding of what's going on in your document.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amscd,amsthm}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[page]{appendix}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage[retainorgcmds]{IEEEtrantools}

\usepackage{supertabular} % tableaux qui tiennent sur plusieurs pages

%\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
%%\usepackage{amsfonts}
%%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
%%\usepackage{amssymb}
\def\ds{}
\usepackage{latexsym}
%%\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{syntonly}
\usepackage{tracefnt}
%%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\addtolength{\textwidth}{1.6cm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace} % permet de définir l'interligne
\usepackage{a4wide}
%\usepackage{xtab}



%\textheight 22.5cm \textwidth 15.8cm
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{hmargin=3cm,vmargin=3cm}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LYX's packages
\usepackage{float}
%%%\usepackage{amsmath}
%%%\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{esint}
\PassOptionsToPackage{normalem}{ulem}
\usepackage{ulem}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\bea}{\begin{eqnarray*}}
\newcommand{\eea}{\end{eqnarray*}}
\newcommand{\cc}{\mathcal}
\newcommand{\bb}{\mathbb}
\newcommand{\evacc}{\right.}
\newcommand{\bp}{\left(}
\newcommand{\ep}{\right)}
\newcommand{\bint}{\left[}
\newcommand{\eint}{\right]}
%\newcommand{\bea}{\begin{eqnarray*}}
%\newcommand{\eea}{\end{eqnarray*}}
\newcommand{\bnorme}{\left\|}
\newcommand{\enorme}{\right\|}
\newcommand{\babsolu}{\left|}
\newcommand{\eabsolu}{\right|}
\newcommand{\ba}{\begin{array}}
\newcommand{\ea}{\end{array}}
\newcommand{\bdes}{\begin{description}}
\newcommand{\edes}{\end{description}}
\newcommand{\benu}{\begin{enumerate}}
\newcommand{\eenu}{\end{enumerate}}
\newcommand{\implique}{\Rightarrow}
\newcommand{\ssi}{\Leftrightarrow}
\newcommand{\associe}{\mapsto}
\newcommand{\avaleur}{\rightarrow}
\newcommand{\rn}{$\mathbb{R}^N$}
\newcommand{\sla}{\textbackslash}
%\newcommand{\pp}{\textit{Preuve.}}
\newcommand{\bdisp}{\begin{displaymath}}
\newcommand{\edisp}{\begin{displaymath}}
\newcommand{\bsplit}{\begin{split}}
\newcommand{\esplit}{\end{split}}
\newcommand{\petit}{\footnotesize}
\newtheorem{deff}{Définition}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[deff]{Lemme}
\newtheorem{prop}[deff]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{thm}[deff]{Théorème}
\newtheorem{coro}[deff]{Corollaire}
\newtheorem{rmq}[deff]{Remarque}
\newcommand{\pre}{{\textit{\petit{{\textbf{Démonstration.  }}}}}}
\newcommand{\p}{\mathbb{P}}
\newcommand{\pp}{\mathbb{P}^{'}}
\newcommand{\ppp}{\mathbb{P}^{''}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\BB}{\mathscr{B}}
\newcommand{\KK}{\mathscr{K}}
\newcommand{\CC}{\mathcal{C}}
\newcommand{\X}{\mathsf{X}}

\newcommand{\YY}{\mathsf{Y}}

\newcommand{\HH}{\mathsf{H}}
\newcommand{\XX}{\mathsf{X}}
\newcommand{\NN}{\mathsf{N}}
\newcommand{\RR}{\mathsf{R}}
\newcommand{\EE}{\mathsf{E}}
\newcommand{\FF}{\mathsf{F}}
\newcommand{\MM}{\mathsf{M}}
\newcommand*{\defeq}{\mathrel{\vcenter{\baselineskip0.5ex \lineskiplimit0pt
                     \hbox{\scriptsize.}\hbox{\scriptsize.}}}% definie le symbole :&=
                     &=}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\textbf{Fonctions de référence}

\allowdisplaybreaks
\begin{align*}
\tau(n)&=\mbox{card\,}\{\, p\mid \text{$p$ divise $n$}\,\}
&
\mu(n)&=\begin{cases}0&\text{si $n\not\in \pp$}\\ (-1)^{\tau(n)} &\text{si $n\in \pp$}\end{cases} \mbox{ \petit(fonction de Möbius)}\\[1\baselineskip]
\delta(n)&=\sum_{k/n}\mu(k)
&
\Lambda (n)&=
\begin{cases} 
0       &\text{si $n\not\in \ppp$}\\
\log(p) &\text{si $n= \p^\nu$}
\end{cases}
\mbox{ \petit{(fonction de Mangoldt)}}\\[1\baselineskip]
b(n)&=\sum_{kl=n}\Lambda(k)\,\Lambda (l) -\Lambda(n)\log(n)
&
c(n)&=\sum_{kl=n}\Lambda(k)\,\Lambda (l)+\Lambda(n)\log(n)\\[1\baselineskip]
[x]&=\sum_{k\leq x}1\text{ \petit(partie entière de $x$)}
& 
\beta(x)&=x-[x] \text{ \petit(partie fractionnaire de $x$)}\\[1\baselineskip]
\pi(x)&=\mbox{card}\{\, p\in\p\mid p\leq x\,\}
&
\pi'(x)&=\mbox{card}\{\, p'\in\pp\mid p'\leq x \,\} \\[1\baselineskip]
U(x)&={\sum_{k\leq x}\frac{x}{k}}
&
M(x)&={\sum_{k\leq x} \mu(k)} \mbox{ \petit{(fonction de Mertens)}}\\[1\baselineskip]
V(x)&=\sum_{k\leq x}\frac{x}{k}\log\bp\frac{x}{k}\ep
& 
\varphi(x)&=\babsolu M(x)\eabsolu \log^2 x-2x\log x\\[1\baselineskip]
\sigma(x)&={\sup_{t\geq x}\babsolu \frac{M(t)}{t}\eabsolu}
& 
\nu_p(x)&=\bint \frac{\log (x)}{\log (p)}\eint=
\begin{cases}
0                           &\text{ si $p>x$}\\
\max\{\, \nu\mid p^\nu\leq x \,\}&\text{ si $p\leq x$}
\end{cases}\\[1\baselineskip]
\theta(x)&=\sum_{p\leq x}\log(p)
&
\Psi(x)&=\sum_{p\leq x}\nu_p(x)\log(p)=
\sum_{n\leq x}\Lambda (n)\mbox{ \petit(f. de Tchebychev)}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: AMAZING !!! Works perfectly !

Comment: Is it possible to add a vertical line between the two columns?

Comment: @Thibault - The material in the `align*` environment currently already takes up the full width of the textblock. I wouldn't add any extra material (such as a vertical bar) that adds further to the width of the environment.

Comment: I undrestand. But I would like to Know how we can put a vertical line between with this  environment

Comment: @Thibault - The simple answer is that it's not straightforward to add a vertical bar in an `align` (or `align*`) environment. Note that it's very rarely desirable -- and frequently *highly undesirable* -- to provide vertical bars in formal or informal tables. Vertical bars almost always just provide visual clutter and do not contribute to the reader's understanding of the material being presented.

Answer (score 1):

I cleaned up the code a bit and allowed it to break over the page using an `align*` environment. See the comments in the code.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  %%% new
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amscd}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[page]{appendix}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{
%already loaded amsfonts
,bbm}
\usepackage[retainorgcmds]{IEEEtrantools}

\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage{supertabular} % tableaux qui tiennent sur plusieurs pages

%\usepackage{epsfig} no!
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
%already loaded \usepackage{amsfonts}
%already loaded \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
%already loaded \usepackage{amssymb}
\def\ds{\displaystyle}
% no \usepackage{latexsym}
%already loaded \usepackage{amsfonts}
% \usepackage{syntonly}no:-)
% \usepackage{tracefnt}
%already loaded \usepackage{amsmath}
%\addtolength{\textwidth}{1.6cm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace} % permet de définir l'interligne
% no use geometry, as you do below \usepackage{a4wide}
%%\usepackage{xtab} %% commented out because loading this package causes an error



%\textheight 22.5cm \textwidth 15.8cm
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{hmargin=3cm,vmargin=3cm}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LYX's packages
\usepackage{float}
%already loaded \usepackage{amsmath}
%already loaded \usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{esint}
% \PassOptionsToPackage{normalem}{ulem}
% \usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}%simpler


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%don't do this!!!!!
% It's bad style and doesn't work at all with ams alignments
% use environment syntax

% \newcommand{\bea}{\begin{eqnarray*}}
%\newcommand{\eea}{\end{eqnarray*}}
\newcommand{\cc}{\mathcal}
\newcommand{\bb}{\mathbb}
\newcommand{\bacc}{\left\{}
\newcommand{\eacc}{\right\}}
\newcommand{\evacc}{\right.}
\newcommand{\bp}{\left(}
\newcommand{\ep}{\right)}
\newcommand{\bint}{\left[}
\newcommand{\eint}{\right]}
%\newcommand{\bea}{\begin{eqnarray*}}
%\newcommand{\eea}{\end{eqnarray*}}
\newcommand{\bnorme}{\left\|}
\newcommand{\enorme}{\right\|}
\newcommand{\babsolu}{\left|}
\newcommand{\eabsolu}{\right|}
%\newcommand{\ba}{\begin{array}}
%\newcommand{\ea}{\end{array}}
%\newcommand{\bdes}{\begin{description}}
%\newcommand{\edes}{\end{description}}
%\newcommand{\benu}{\begin{enumerate}}
%\newcommand{\eenu}{\end{enumerate}}
\newcommand{\implique}{\Rightarrow}
\newcommand{\ssi}{\Leftrightarrow}
\newcommand{\associe}{\mapsto}
\newcommand{\avaleur}{\rightarrow}
\newcommand{\rn}{$\mathbb{R}^N$}
\newcommand{\sla}{\textbackslash}
%\newcommand{\pp}{\textit{Preuve.}}
%\newcommand{\bdisp}{\begin{displaymath}}
%\newcommand{\edisp}{\begin{displaymath}}
%\newcommand{\bsplit}{\begin{split}}
%\newcommand{\esplit}{\end{split}}
\newcommand{\petit}{\footnotesize} % this does _not_ take an argument
\newtheorem{deff}{Définition}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[deff]{Lemme}
\newtheorem{prop}[deff]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{thm}[deff]{Théorème}
\newtheorem{coro}[deff]{Corollaire}
\newtheorem{rmq}[deff]{Remarque}
\newcommand{\pre}{{\textit{\petit{{\textbf{Démonstration.  }}}}}}
\newcommand{\p}{\mathbb{P}}
\newcommand{\pp}{\mathbb{P}^{'}}
\newcommand{\ppp}{\mathbb{P}^{''}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\BB}{\mathscr{B}}
\newcommand{\KK}{\mathscr{K}}
\newcommand{\CC}{\mathcal{C}}
\newcommand{\X}{\mathsf{X}}

\newcommand{\YY}{\mathsf{Y}}

\newcommand{\HH}{\mathsf{H}}
\newcommand{\XX}{\mathsf{X}}
\newcommand{\NN}{\mathsf{N}}
\newcommand{\RR}{\mathsf{R}}
\newcommand{\EE}{\mathsf{E}}
\newcommand{\FF}{\mathsf{F}}
\newcommand{\MM}{\mathsf{M}}
\newcommand*{\defeq}{\mathrel{\vcenter{\baselineskip0.5ex \lineskiplimit0pt
                     \hbox{\scriptsize.}\hbox{\scriptsize.}}}% definie le symbole :=
                     =}

\begin{document} %%% new


xxxxx

\vspace{12cm}
xxxxxx

\section*{fonctions de référence}% avoid explict font changes

\allowdisplaybreaks
\begin{align*}
{\tau(n)=\mbox{card\,}\bacc p\, /\, p\mbox{ divise }n\eacc}
& {\mu(n)=\bacc\begin{array}{ccc}0&\mbox{ si }
&n\not\in \pp\\ (-1)^{\tau(n)}
&\mbox{ si }&n\in \pp\end{array}\right.} \mbox{\petit(fonction de Möbius)}\\
{{\delta(n)=\sum_{k/n}\mu(k)}}
&\Lambda (n)=\bacc\begin{array}{ccc}0
&\mbox{ si }
&n\not\in \ppp\\
\log(p)
&\mbox{ si }
&n= \p^\nu\end{array}\right.\mbox{\petit (fonction de Mangoldt)}\\
{b(n)=\sum_{kl=n}\Lambda(k)\,\Lambda (l)-\Lambda(n)\log(n)}
&{c(n)=\sum_{kl=n}\Lambda(k)\,\Lambda (l)+\Lambda(n)\log(n)}\\
{[x]=\sum_{k\leq x}1} (\mbox{\petit partie entière de} x)
& \beta(x)=x-[x] (\mbox {\petit partie fractionnaire de } x)\\
\pi(x)=\mbox{card}\bacc p\in\p\,/\, p\leq x\eacc&\pi'(x)=\mbox{card}\bacc p'\in\pp\,/\, p'\leq x\eacc\\
U(x)={\sum_{k\leq x}\frac{x}{k}}&M(x)={\sum_{k\leq x} \mu(k)} \mbox{\petit (fonction de Mertens)}\\
V(x)={\sum_{k\leq x}\frac{x}{k}\log\bp\frac{x}{k}\ep}& \varphi(x)=\babsolu M(x)\eabsolu \log^2 x-2x\log x\\[10pt]
\sigma(x)={\sup_{t\geq x}\babsolu \frac{M(t)}{t}\eabsolu}& \nu_p(x)=\bint \frac{\log (x)}{\log (p)}\eint=\bacc\begin{array}{ccc}0&\mbox{ si }&p>x\\[10pt]
\max\bacc \nu/\ p^\nu\leq x\eacc&\mbox{ si }&p\leq x\end{array}\right.\\[10pt]
\theta(x)={\sum_{p\leq x}\log(p)}&\Psi(x)={\sum_{p\leq x}\nu_p(x)\log(p)}={\sum_{n\leq x}\Lambda (n)}\mbox{\petit (f. de Tchebychev)}
\end{align*}

\end{document} %%% new
```

Comment: unfortunately this did not give the desired result. Everything is centered in the middle for me

Comment: @Thibault it took longer than I'd hoped fixing `\displaystyle{}` and `\petit{}` but you now you have a breaking alignment you should be able to adjust the `&` to match use `&=` for each aligned `=` and `&&` between the columns.